# On/Off icon for boolean field in list_editable modelAdmin

Tags: django, django-admin

When I put my boolean field in list_editable, it's icon change from the nice on/off icon to the legacy checkbox. Is there a way to keep the field editable with the nice icons ?
I think I've already done this, but can't remember how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use you own JavaScript to replace the checkbox with the appropriate image, and use click events to change the image and set the checkbox appropriately.

CSS

```
.hidden {
    position:absolute;
    left:-99999px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS

```
(function($){
    var on_image = '/static/admin/img/admin/icon-yes.gif';
    var off_image = '/static/admin/img/admin/icon-no.gif';

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var $checkbox = $('.checkbox_field input');
        // Can't simply `hide()` as its value will not be posted
        $checkbox.addClass('hidden');
        var $img = $('<img/>');
        if ($checkbox.attr('checked')) {
            $img.attr('href', on_image);
            $img.attr('alt', 'On');
        } else {
            $img.attr('href', off_image);
            $img.attr('alt', 'Off');
        }
        $img.insertAfter($checkbox);

        $img.click(function(){
            var $img = $(this);
            var $checkbox = $img.siblings('input');

            if ($img.attr('href') == on_image) {
                $img.attr('href', off_image);
                $img.attr('alt', 'Off');
                $checkbox.attr('checked', false);
            } else {
                $img.attr('href', on_image);
                $img.attr('alt', 'On');
                $checkbox.attr('checked', true);
            }
        });
    });
)(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, which is usefull, but I really think there was a "django way" to do it, i'll post it if I find it back...